# NP_NAT error when attempting to import pandas_market_calender

Tags: python-3.9

I'm trying things out on windows vs linux where I have this working in 3.8 and 3.9.5, but not on windows using anaconda

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
from datetime import time
import pandas as pd
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas_market_calendars\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .calendar_registry import get_calendar, get_calendar_names
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas_market_calendars\calendar_registry.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .exchange_calendars_mirror import *
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas_market_calendars\exchange_calendars_mirror.py", line 9, in <module>
    import exchange_calendars
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\exchange_calendars\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .calendar_utils import (
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\exchange_calendars\calendar_utils.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .always_open import AlwaysOpenCalendar
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\exchange_calendars\always_open.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .exchange_calendar import ExchangeCalendar
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\exchange_calendars\exchange_calendar.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .calendar_helpers import (
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\exchange_calendars\calendar_helpers.py", line 6, in <module>
    NP_NAT = np.array([pd.NaT], dtype=np.int64)[0]
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NaTType
```

'

Comment: I get the same error. Any idea how to fix it? I got this error message with Python 3.8 on Ubuntu.

Comment: When I run this in jupyterlab inside an oracle linux vm running 3.9.5 no issue

Comment: oddly enough it doesn't work in 3.9.6 in the same environment.  Something must have changed between 3.9.5 and 3.9.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with the underlying exchange_calendars package (https://github.com/gerrymanoim/exchange_calendars). It appears that error has been fixed in that package. If you update the exchange_calendars package everything will work fine. Nothing to do in this package.

Fix: gerrymanoim/exchange_calendars#41

Answer (score 4):

Posted a github bug

indeed something changed and the culprit is pandas

https://github.com/rsheftel/pandas_market_calendars/issues/137

to solve, install pandas==1.2.5 and it will work